# i get a black screen using while on kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

whenever I start the program the screen turns black which dont happens when i don't use the while statement, what im trying to say is that while (email dont contains @ !! email length is <6 the button opacity should be 0.5 and when the statement is true the button opacity is 1f and you can press it

```
registrar_button_register.alpha = 0.5f

        while(email.contains('@') || password.length()<5){

        }
        registrar_button_register.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(200)
        registrar_button_register.setOnClickListener {// and code goes on...
```

what I'm specting is that if email has @ and the password has 6 characters the opacity will be 1f and it will be possible to press the button, I know that email while statement should be that doesnt contain @ but i dont know how to do it

for those who dont understand what im trying to achieve try to signup on instagram without a @ on the email or a short password

maybe delegation or some sort of observable mechanism could be use here??

Comment: All valid email addresses will have an @ symbol so you have an infinite loop, why not a simple if statement, this logic/code doesn't make much sense?

Comment: thats what i mean i what that only if they have @ (email must be valid) the opacity goes to 100% same way that instagram does

Comment: im just trying to make it cooler i could have a if stament saying if(email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty){ Toast.makeText(this, "type email a password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()} but is not good enough

Comment: Use a `TextWatcher` with the `EditText` fields and check with an if statement in the callbacks only when the text changes - looping is the wrong logic.

Answer (score -1):

You have an infinite `while` loop. To check if a condition is true, just use a `if` statement. Something along the following lines should work,

```
//Use && to ensure both conditions are true
if(email.contains('@') && password.length()<5){
  registrar_button_register.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(200)
  registrar_button_register.setOnClickListener {// and code goes on...
}
```

Comment: what im trying to do with the while is that until the email has @ and the password is long enough doesnt go to the next thing which is bringing the opacity up and letting the button do their thing

Comment: im just trying to make it cooler i could have a if stament saying if(email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty){ Toast.makeText(this, "type email a password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()} but is not good enough

Comment: try to enter in the instagram app a email without @, you will see what happens to the register button that is what im trying to achieve

Comment: In that case, don't just use a while loop (infinite while loops will block the UI thread). You need to add an else condition that prompts(toast, snack bar, etc) the user to 'correct' his email. After he does so, then run the function again.

Comment: try to put a email without @ on instagram log in

Comment: and you will see what im trying to do, the only way to do that is with a loop that is checking until password has 6+ characters and email has @

Comment: Check @Mark Keens comment, he mentioned the TextWatcher as a solution, which is the answer for the problem.